# Using GraphQL Fragment for the Whole Return Values

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm having trouble reusing fragments inside queries.

Dependencies:

- @apollo/client: 3.5.6
- graphql: 15.8.0
- react: 17.0.2

I'm importing gql from @apollo/client.

This is my fragment:

```
export const totalRecipeReturnValFragment = gql`
  fragment totalRecipeReturnValFragment on RecipeOutput {
    _id
    instructions
    sections {
      name
      ingredients {
        name
        amount
        unit
        isRangedAmount
        topRange
        bottomRange
      }
    }
    name
    duration
    userId
    preparations {
      _id
      stringifiedTime
      occasion
      rating
      comment
    }
  }
`;
```

When I'm using just in a mutation, with a "variable", it works as expected:

```
export const updateRecipe = gql`
  mutation updateRecipe($updatedRecipe: RecipeUpdateInput!) {
    updateRecipe(updatedRecipe: $updatedRecipe) {
      success
      errorMessage
      recipeAfterUpdate {
        ...totalRecipeReturnValFragment
      }
    }
  }
  ${totalRecipeReturnValFragment}
`;
```

But, I have a few queries in which I'd like to use just the fragment, without a "variable".

This is one of the original queries:

```
export default gql`
  query getUserRecipes($userId: String!) {
    getUserRecipes(userId: $userId) {
      _id
      instructions
      sections {
        name
        ingredients {
          name
          amount
          unit
          isRangedAmount
          topRange
          bottomRange
        }
      }
      name
      duration
      userId
      preparations {
        _id
        stringifiedTime
        comment
        occasion
        rating
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

This is what I've been trying to use:

```
export default gql`
  query getUserRecipes($userId: String!) {
    getUserRecipes(userId: $userId) {
      ...totalRecipeReturnValFragment
    }
  }
  ${totalRecipeReturnValFragment}
`;
```

The above query compiles, but the data in the code doesn't contain any field.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I used `cache: new InMemoryCache({ addTypename: false })` in my ApolloClient. Once I removed the `{ addTypename: false }`, it worked like a charm.